# Change Layout order using Effects Package: R

Tags: r, lattice, effects

I want to plot only one category of a multinomial regression using the Effects package.

Example:

```
library(nnet)
m1 <- multinom(Species ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Width + Sepal.Length, data = iris)
plt <- effect("Sepal.Width * Petal.Width", m1, x.var = "Sepal.Width")
plot(plt, x.var = "Sepal.Width",
 lattice = list(strip = list(factor.names = F)),
 confint = list(style="auto", col = "black"),
 axes = list(grid = T, 
             x = list(rug = F)))
```

This gives me the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdOw5.png

Is there any way to plot only, for instance, the class Versicolor?
Already tried with `layout()` but I can only get as far as plotting Setosa and Versicolor:

```
plot(plt, x.var = "Sepal.Width",
 lattice = list(strip = list(factor.names = F),
                layout = c(5, 2, 1)),
 confint = list(style="auto", col = "black"),
 axes = list(grid = T, 
             x = list(rug = F)))
```

If I change `layout = c(5, 2, 1)` to `layout = c(5, 1, 1)` it only displays Setosa.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found was to use ggplot2.

First I had to convert my `object` (from `effect()`) to a data frame and then go from there:

**Example:**

```
m1 <- multinom(Species ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Width + Sepal.Length, data = iris)
plt <- effect("Sepal.Width * Petal.Width", m1)

plt_df <- data.frame(plt) # creating a data frame
```

And to plot with ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data = plt_df, aes(x = Sepal.Width, 
                        y = prob.versicolor,
                        ymin = L.prob.versicolor,  # Lower CI
                        ymax = U.prob.versicolor)) + # Upper CI
geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.2) +  # For CI
geom_line() +  
facet_wrap(~Petal.Width, ncol = 5) +
# Few things to custoimze
scale_y_continuous("Predicted Probabilities Y",
                     # axes on top / right sides
                     sec.axis = dup_axis(),
                     breaks = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, .75, 1),
                     labels = c("0%" , "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")) + 
scale_x_continuous("Sepal Width") + 
theme_bw() +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        strip.placement = "outside",   
        ## If you want to point axis ticks inwards:
        ### (2.75pt is the default axis tick length here)
        # axis.ticks.length = unit(-2.75, "pt"),
        ## do not show top / right axis labels:
        # axis.text.x.top = element_blank(),  
        ## For Secondary Axis:
        #axis.text.y.right = element_blank(),
        ## As Above, Don't show axis titles:
        # axis.title.x.top = element_blank(),      
        axis.title.y.right = element_blank(),
        # Change the distance between y axis title and ticks:
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(
          t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocVJO.png